# Tooltip using hover not working with div?

Tags: css, html

```
  <div id="content">
<div class="container">
  <!--start side column-->
  <div class="side-col">
    <div class="searchmodule-header-container"> 
    </div>
    <div class="searchmodule-header-container">
      <div class="searchmodule-header">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="searchmodule-content-container">
      <div class="searchmodule-content">
        <div class="menu">

        </div>
        <div class="menu">
          <ul>

            <li><a href="#" class="tooltiplink">Title <span class="tooltip"><span class="top"></span> <span class="middle">   I triggered this using Jsp dynamic page  </span><span class="bottom"></span></span></a></li>

          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="main-col">
    <div class="content-header">

    </div>

      <div class="form-container">
      </div>
</div>
```

In css i just used images to sandwich the content . But when i hover on the link the tooltip is only visible in its container . So how can i get the tooltip(let it be image ) irrespective of the div .

Thanks in advance

Comment: I do not understand this question at all.

Comment: What makes your tooltip, is it CSS, jQuery? We need a better explanation and perhaps a live example would greatly benefit you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, I think you are having the tooltip show up in the 'area' it was defined in and you want it to pop up and hover/float near/over the element.

You would need to define your tooltips `position [relative/absolute]`.  That should float it above the rest of the content, with a combination of `z-index: value`.

Hopefully that is what you are asking, I am making many assumptions here based on your question.

Comment: thanx a ton Jakub ..thats what i want and can you be more precise i tried using Z index but :(

Comment: `z-index` sets the 'stack order' (think layers in photoshop) of elements, z-index:0 is the default (i believe) and setting a `z-index:1` would put an element into the 1 higher level (layer in ps terms). More info here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use title property to show tooltips for DIV

**example**

```
<div title='This is DIV area' ></div>
```